# Use tuples with Entity Framework Contains statement

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have an entity whose reference is a composite of an identifier and an environment. I want to implement a function to allow the user to pass a list of tuples of (ID, Environment) and return back the required entities. Is it possible to use Contains() in such scenarios? How? With a simple reference, it is as simple as

```
model.MyEntities.Where(e => myIds.Contains(e.Id))
```

**EDIT**: To clarify, I am not looking for how to use Contains() method to retrieve a list of IDs; the line I wrote above does this. What I am looking for is to be able to retrieve a list of entities matching tuples of (ID, Environment) rather than just ID.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6912733/linq-to-entities-where-in-clause-with-multiple-columns - I'd say your best bet is to `Union()` the queries for the IDs together and hope the SQL optimizer can make sense of that.

Comment: Another option would be using LinqKit to dynamically build a chain of `OR`s.

Answer (score 1):

Latest version of Entity Framework allows you to do a `Contains` on an array of primitive types (I think it works on an `IEnumerable` too now, I haven't tried).

If you match solely on your `Id` (ie, your match is good if one of the Tuple's ID is the `MyEntity.Id`, this will work (I'm using `Tuple` losely here as your case seems to be an actual object; `Tuple` only has `ItemN` properties):

```
var containedIds = yourListOfTuples.Select(t => t.Id).ToArray();
model.MyEntities.Where(e => containedIds.Contains(e.Id));
```

This will effectively translate into a `WHERE ... IN ([the Ids in containedIds])` statement in SQL.

Comment: Just to expand on that, it's important to convert the tuples to a normal array, because EF cannot convert a tuple to SQL inherently.

Comment: @MystereMan Correct. I specified `array of primitive types` but I should have been more explicit.

Comment: That doesn't really answer the question. I already actually mentioned above how to use Contains() for IDs. My problem is whether Entity Framework supports using Contains() with composite keys, e.g. myTuples.Contains(new {Id, Environment}).

Comment: @Rafid Last time I investigated this, the answer seemed to be "nope, not as far as anyone else can see".

Comment: @Rafid Contains will work on primitive types only, unfortunately.