# LINQ query that searches for tuples

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of tuples (`List<Tuple<string,string>>`) of `Fname` and `Version` as input.

eg.

```
[('firstname1','1.0.1'), ('firstname2','2.3.3'), ('firstname3','4.4.1')]
```

Is it possible to write a LINQ query that essentially does what the following SQL query does and returns tuples of `Name` and `AttribX`?

```
SELECT e.Name, a.AttribX
FROM Element e
JOIN Attributes a ON a.AId=e.EAId
where (a.FName='firstname1' and a.Version='1.0.1')
   OR (a.Fname='firstname2' and a.Version='2.3.3')
   OR (a.Fname='firstname3' and a.Version='4.4.1')
```

There are about a 1000 tuples in the input.

Comment: The 101 Linq samples page is a good starting point. Linq supports joining two lists, so there are some samples: https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b

Comment: Are you wanting to use the tuples as a filter to an actual SQL Linq query?

Comment: Yes, this is Entity Framework

Comment: With 1000 tuples, you are building one hell of a SQL query from this, are you sure there's no other option?

Comment: The number of input tuples is always around 1000. :(

Comment: You may well run into the 2100 parameter limit - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/656167/hitting-the-2100-parameter-limit-sql-server-when-using-contains .

Comment: It's getting less ad less clear. Are you really looking at 1000 `OR ( ... )` clauses?  Are your tuples your Input, Output or both?

Comment: Pretty sure the tuples are the input, which means 1000 of them would create 2000 parameters, dangerously close to the limit.

Comment: Yes tuples are in the input

Comment: Didn't know of the parameter limit. Would it help to break up the input, issue multiple queries and combine results?

Comment: Yes - read the link I provided @devnull .

Comment: @DavidG: And this is why we shouldn't use parameterised SQL and instead just create it through string concatenation. ;-) (And in case anybody is unsure yes, I am joking - do not do this!).

Comment: @Chris You've suggested it, now that means someone will use it in an answer and get upvotes!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `Where` clause could be (if using LINQ to Objects):

```
var results = yourData.Where(z => yourListOfTuples.Contains(new Tuple<string, string>(z.FirstName, z.Version)))
```

Another option to try (against Entity Framework):

```
var tuples = yourListOfTuples.Select(z => z.Item1 + "-" + z.Item2).ToList();
var results = yourData.Where(z => tuples.Contains(z.FirstName + "-" + z.Version))
```

*The second code sample just concatenates the two fields - this will negatively impact database lookups (since it will likely have to do scans rather than seeks). You may also have issues if `FirstName` or `LastName` contains `-` for example. On the upside it will use only 1000 parameters rather than 2000. :)*

Comment: This won't work if the source is an Entity Framework db set.

Comment: Great point @DavidG ! If the source data (i.e. `yourData`) is Entity Framework etc then this won't work. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17595105/use-tuples-with-entity-framework-contains-statement .

Comment: @DavidG OP explicitly said he/she has a list of tuples

Comment: @Esko Yes, as input but it's not explicitly stated what the source is. I suspect the tuples are actually a filter for a DbSet query. For example, where does `AttribX` come from here?

Comment: AttribX is a column in the DB.

Comment: The question is a litlle zigzag but the Tuples are the desired output. You can see that because a Tuple can never have an `AId` property.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Well, it can (sort of!) if you're using the latest version of C# of course :)

Comment: Is there a case where the first solution would not work, but the second would?

Comment: "will work" and "should use this method" are often in opposition, and that's where I stand on this - I'd recommend against it.

Comment: Hard to say as we don't know the context of the app, but the 1000 tuples must have come from somewhere, hopefully the database, so I'd be tempted to leave them in there and just do a join. Or, insert them in there and use that as the join. Batching is also an option, but again that depends on many factors.

Comment: Thanks, option 2 works fine although very slow. Takes around 2 min. I do a bunch of joins too in the query @DavidG the tuples come from large xml files, not DB.

Comment: Then consider adding them to the database and avoiding the use of tuples altogether. There's rarely a good use case for them (other than the newer C#7 version.)

Answer (score 0):

If you're generating SQL, you can avoid string concatenation by building the `where` clause somewhat explicitly:

```
Expression<Func<Attributes, bool>> inTuples = a => false;
inTuples = yourListOfTuples.Aggregate(inTuples, (predicate, tuple) => predicate
    .Or(a => a.FName == tuple.Item1 && a.Version == tuple.Item2));
```

The `Or` in the above snippet is a simple utility for combining two expressions. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12497283/1713149) for the code, as well as the `And` counterpart. These two extension methods are invaluable in working with expressions.

You can now use this `inTuples` expression to filter a query of `Attributes`, and the generated `where` clause will match the desired form:

```
var filteredQuery = attributesQuery.Where(inTuples).AsEnumerable();
```

You may have to do a bit of finagling to transform the result to a list of tuples:

```
var resultingTuples = filteredQuery
    .Select(a => new {a.Name, a.AttribX})
    .AsEnumerable()
    .Select(a => (a.FName, a.AttribX))
    .ToList();
```

(Note that I returned `a.FName` instead of `e.Name` to keep the example simple.)

Comment: I got an error `No overload for method 'Or' takes 1 arguments` in `...(inTuples, (predicate, tuple) => predicate.OR...` any ideas?

Comment: Ah, found the answer from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1266742/how-to-append-to-an-expression/1267061  I need to build a function extension for OR as described in the link.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I've added clarity to my answer.

Comment: It compiles fine, but when I tried running it, I get error `The binary operator Or is not defined for the types 'System.Func'2[MainDB.tblOrder,System.Boolean]' and 'System.Func'2[MainDB.tblOrder,System.Boolean]'."}` in the Or statement. I ended up using PredicateBuilder which I get it from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6912733/linq-to-entities-where-in-clause-with-multiple-columns . It is very similar with your answer. I like your answer but can't figure out why it doesn't work :(